# How to count unique values in java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I want to count the number of unique values in an array but I'm having trouble counting in the correct way.

```
int uniqueNumbers = 1;
Arrays.sort(n);

if (n.length == 0) {
    uniqueNumbers = 0;
}

for ( int i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] != n[i - 1]) {
        uniqueNumbers++;
    }
}
```

The problem is if an integer appears several times it still counts it as one unique number, when I want it not to be counted as a unique number.

Comment: I would recommend to create a [MRE] and then debug the program. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- Please read: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

A nested loop to track a unique number and discard it can help resolve this task:

```java
public static int countUnique(int ... n) {
    Arrays.sort(n);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));

    int uniqueNumbers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        boolean unique = true;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n.length && n[i] == n[j]; j++, i++) {
            unique = false;
        }
        if (unique) {
            uniqueNumbers++;
        }
    }
    return uniqueNumbers;
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(countUnique(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4));
System.out.println(countUnique(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4));
System.out.println(countUnique(2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6]
3
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
1
[1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
0
```

However, because of sorting the input array, the complexity of this algorithm is `O(N log N)`.

---

If it is allowed to use `Set` to track duplicates using the fact that `Set::add` returns `false` when an element already exists in the set, this may be implemented as follows (also, the input array does not need to be sorted, so this algorithm has `O(N)` complexity):

```java
public static int countUniqueSets(int ... n) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    
    Set<Integer> ones = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> dups = new HashSet<>();
    
    for (int x : n) {
        if (!ones.add(x)) {
            dups.add(x);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("distinct: " + ones);
    System.out.println("duplicates: " + dups);

    return ones.size() - dups.size();
}
```

Output for the same tests:

```java
[2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4]
distinct: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
duplicates: [2, 4]
3
[2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4]
distinct: [1, 2, 3, 4]
duplicates: [1, 2, 4]
1
[2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4]
distinct: [1, 2, 4]
duplicates: [1, 2, 4]
0
```

---

Another approach using Stream API is to build a frequency map using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.counting` or `Collectors.summingInt` and then count the entries in the map with `frequency = 1`:

```java
public static int countUniqueStream(int ... n) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    
    return (int) Arrays.stream(n)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     x -> x,
                     Collectors.counting()
                 )) // Map<Integer, Long>
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(e -> 1 == e.getValue())
                 .count();
}

public static int countUniqueStreamInt(int ... n) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    
    return Arrays.stream(n)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    x -> x,
                    Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)
                 ))  // Map<Integer, Integer>
                 .entrySet().stream()
                 .filter(e -> 1 == e.getValue())
                 .collect(Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize a set to add all the numbers, as won't allow duplicates.

```
int uniqueNumbers = 1;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    Arrays.sort(n);

    if (n.length == 0) {
        uniqueNumbers = 0;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        set.add(n[i];
    }

System.out.println(set.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do so e.g. using `Stream` API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr= {1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1,4,3};
        long uniqueCount = Arrays.stream(arr)
                            .distinct()
                            .count();
        
        System.out.println(uniqueCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the array content to set and then get the set size.

```java
Set<Integer> targetSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(n));
targetSet.size()
```

`n` is your array name as appearing in the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a whole inner loop, you just need to check the two adjacent numbers while respecting the array limits.

```
private int countUnique (int... n)
{
    int uniqueNumbers = 0;
    if (n.length < 2)
    {
        uniqueNumbers = n.length;
    }
    else
    {
        Arrays.sort (n);
        logger.info ("Data %s", Arrays.toString (n));
        // Check first element
        if (n[0] != n[1])
        {
            uniqueNumbers++;
        }
        // Check last element
        if (n[n.length - 2] != n[n.length - 1])
        {
            uniqueNumbers++;
        }
        // Check middle elements
        for (int i = 1; i < n.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((n[i - 1] != n[i]) && (n[i + 1] != n[i]))
            {
                uniqueNumbers++;
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueNumbers;
}
```